# Unexpected padding on side of drawer

Tags: flutter

I'm not sure if this is due to using nested scaffolds, but my drawer has a mysterious padding or margin on the left side of it when it is extended. Changing the width of the sizedbox doesn't change the size of the whitespace either. Also the drawer is really finicky to open.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class NewHome extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_NewHomeState createState() => _NewHomeState();
}

class _NewHomeState extends State<NewHome> {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text("App"),
  ),
  body: Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      Align(
        alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
        child: SizedBox(
          width: 285.0,
          child: Scaffold(
            drawer: Drawer(
              child: Container(
                color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Container(
        color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
        width: 75.0,
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[],
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
}
}
```

Screenshots:

Closed:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRaFT.png

Expected:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0yL7.png

Actual:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOHn3.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that flutter builds widgets on top of each other as they are created. This means that the first widget in a stack is below the second one and so on. So the way I solved this was by putting the first container which has the scaffold child in first, with a padding, this allowed the second container which will always be visible to go onto the padding while the drawer can still be opened nicely.

```
class _NewHomeState extends State<NewHome> {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text("App"),
  ),
  body: Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 74.0),
        child: Container(
          child: Scaffold(
            drawer: Drawer(
              child: Container(
                color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Container(
        color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
        width: 75.0,
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[],
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all let me explain why doesn't it work properly. First of all, it is aligned to center, therefore it starts from the center and cause this issue. Secondly, since it was at center and you use a stack, you need to find the exact spot the start the drawer, that's why it was acting flaky. For solving it:

```
class NewHome extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NewHomeState createState() => _NewHomeState();
}

class _NewHomeState extends State<NewHome> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("App"),
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          //Deleted the blue box because I don't understand why you need it and it was blocking the swipe zone of the drawer
          Container(
            width: 285.0,
            child: Scaffold(
              drawer: Drawer(
                child: Container(
                  color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

For solution, I played around with the official documentation [from here](https://flutter.io/docs/cookbook/design/drawer)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final appTitle = 'Drawer Demo';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: appTitle,
      home: MyHomePage(title: appTitle),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;

  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text(title)),
      body: Scaffold(
        drawer: Drawer(
          // Add a ListView to the drawer. This ensures the user can scroll
          // through the options in the Drawer if there isn't enough vertical
          // space to fit everything.
          child: ListView(
            // Important: Remove any padding from the ListView.
            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            children: <Widget>[
              ListTile(
                title: Text('Item 1'),
                onTap: () {
                  // Update the state of the app
                  // ...
                  // Then close the drawer
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
              ),
              ListTile(
                title: Text('Item 2'),
                onTap: () {
                  // Update the state of the app
                  // ...
                  // Then close the drawer
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The box on the left side was going to hold images which I wanted always visible and I wanted it so that when you swipe right it extends the blue-grey box with the images so that a description is visible. If that makes sense.

Comment: Okay I see. So your question was "Unexpected padding on side of drawer" and I believe it answers with the answer above.

Comment: I added my own answer, when I made your change i realized how the widgets were built.

Comment: No, it's building on top of eachother because of the Stack. But anyway, if my answer helped, you can accept it.